# Multiple graphs in a single plot with a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, quandl

I am trying to display in a single plot n graphs, n being the number of U.S states number.

The compiler doesn't like those 2 lines`x[j] = df['Date'] y[j] = df['Value']`

=> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```python
import quandl
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
j = 0
x = []
y = []

for i in states[0][0][1:]:
        df = quandl.get("FMAC/HPI_"+i, authtoken="yourtoken" )
        df = df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
        x[j] = df['Date']
        y[j] = df['Value']
        j += 1

plt.plot(x[j],y[j])
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('House prices')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: First, you haven't defined `x` and `y`. So put somewhere `x = []; y=[]`. Second, you would need to append the new items, since in the jth step, x[j] doesn't actually exist. Use x.append(...). There might be further issues concerning the plotting a list of dataframes, which I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for the help, going to search about the other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem with this particular error is that you are using the `inplace` argument and assigning back to variable df.  When using inplace argument equals to True, the return is None.

```
print(type(df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)))
NoneType

print(type(df.reset_index(drop=False)))
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Use either `inplace=True` and don't assign back to df:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
```

or use default for inplace=False and assign back to variable df

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=False)
```

There are some other logic errors here.

## EDIT to get a working chart (limit to 20 for testing)

```
for i in states[0][0][1:20]:
        df = quandl.get("FMAC/HPI_"+i, authtoken="yourtoken" )
        df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
        plt.plot('Date','Value',data=df)


# plt.plot(x[j],y[j])
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.title('House prices')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, really appreciated.

Starting Python and those libraries few days ago, got to improve :D